# Different font SIZES in a text editor, based on script (alphabet) type (that is, per Unicode code-block)

Tags: fonts, text-editors, unicode

Some non-Latin-based scripts (alphabets) have more detail in their glyphs than do the Latin-based-script equivalents, and typically need a larger font to give the same degree of legibility (resolution-wise).

Sometimes, both script types need to be present in the same file.

[Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) allows different font **SIZES** (and colour, etc.) courtesy of syntax-highlighting.

This allows me to display a larger-fonted non-Latin-based script in a // **BIG-FONT comment**.
Although this has been quite handy for me in some situations, it is quite limited.

A *word processor* can handle this scenario, but I'm not interested in that. I want a nice simple(?) plain(?) **text editor** to do it on a per **script-type** basis, for example, mixing Latin-1 and Devanagari (and Mandarin, etc.).

Such a thing may not exits, but Notepad++ has shown that a simple(?) plain(?) text editor is capable of it.

Does such a text editor exist?

Why not a word processor?  Because GCC and Python don't like that format! But UTF-8 is fine.

Comment: This can be done with Fontconfig, but GTK+ on Windows doesn't use Fontconfig by default so you'd have to rebuild.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio.. I've heard that Emacs can do it, but it will be a while before I feel brave enough to venture there .. (but some day I hope to.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Emacs*** can concurrently display different font sizes...Here is the [unix.stackexchange Question/Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6922/text-editor-with-font-size-selection-for-specific-human-languages-ie-unicode-bl) about it, and here is an example

[image]

This isn't the complete answer (yet), but from what I"ve read so far, Emacs can display different fonts based on "Human Language", but I need to learn how to drive Emacs first... :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Ctrl-+ in Notepad++ to quickly enlarge the font size whenever you need it.

That shortcut works in many apps, including recent versions of IE and all Firefox versions.

Comment: What you have described is Zooming.  ---  This is not what I mean.   I mean that AT THE SAME TIME Latin script(letters) are 12 point, and Devanagari are 20 point. (... but thanks for your reply)